# Getting SSL certificate of server in iOS webview application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to get the Self signed SSL certificate from the server and display details of it giving the user an option to go ahead or not. If he goes ahead, I need to get the certificate and add to my application just like Safari. For now I'm able to ignore SSL certificate using:

```
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:    (NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod]isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    return NO;
}
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
  [[challenge sender]useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

I need to know how to add self signed cert's to my application root.

Comment: What is *my application root*?

Comment: I mean maintaining certificate store in my application and pushing this certificate just like how safari does it.